keystore.jks file store device fingerprint
I want to know whether when we create keystore.jks file from Android Studio, device related data is stored in it or not.
Data entered during the generation of a keystore from Android Studio, such as full name, organization, state, and country code, can be read from the keystore file using lightweight KeyStore Explorer.
but i want to know that device-related data is also stored in it or not, such as the device on which this keystore.jks file was generated, like IP or MAC address.
